# HackerRank Runtime Error in Simple Python 3 if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, runtime-error

```
def findNumber(arr, k):
    if k in arr:
        print( "YES" )
    else:
        print( "NO" )

if __name__ == '__main__':


    arr_count = int(input().strip())

    arr = []

    for _ in range(arr_count):
        arr_item = int(input().strip())
        arr.append(arr_item)

    k = int(input().strip())

    result = findNumber(arr, k)

    fptr.write(result + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

While this runs just fine on Pycharm, on HackerRank i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 42, in <module>
    fptr.write(result + '\n')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Would really appreciate if you could point out what the error might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `def findNumber(arr, k):` does not return anything, so it returns `None` implicitly.

These lines

> ```
> result = findNumber(arr, k)  
> fptr.write(result + '\n')
> ```

then try to add `None` and a string together - which does not work.

Instead of printing inside your function, `return "Yes"` or `"No`".

Comment: thank you so much, really appreciate the help and how clear you were :)

Answer (score 0):

findNumber returns Nothing, so it automatically returns **None**. You have to replace the "print" in your function with return statements.